# CSS not linked on All Site Content

Tags: master-page, css

I created a master page and custom CSS file to brand the root site of on my SP10 server.  I then applied this master page to all subsites.  The style is applied properly on all sites except when I click the "All Site Content" link from one of the subsites.  In this case, it still uses my master page but fails to apply the CSS.

The master page files links to the CSS with `../..Style Library/My.css` (as inserted by SPD).  This normally resolves properly to `domain/Style Library/My.css` but from the "All Site Content" (and possibly other undiscovered pages) it is trying to load `domain/_subsite_/Style Library/My.css`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try using `<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/My.css %>" After="corev4.css" runat="server"/>` to resolve a full path in the masterpage, though I have a funny feeling that might only work in Publishing Pages...

Comment: It works for all site templates if the css file is accessable by specified URL.

Comment: But does it work in Foundation? Think that's what I should've said :P

Comment: The CssRegistration is a part of SharePoint Foundation 2010 Class Libraries. Thus I think it works on it :P

Comment: Yeah CssReg is, but I'm on about $SPUrl, I'm sure I've seen that break in Foundation...

Comment: Do note, however, that the <% $SPUrl token will not resolve in SharePoint Foundation (SPF). In SPF, you will need to specify the location using a hard coded URL. Unfortunately this will be limiting if you want to use different CSS files for different languages (since you won’t have a ~language token). ([Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2010/04/09/working-with-the-sharepoint-theming-engine.aspx)). I like SharePoint !

Comment: Nothing stopping you creating a new, very simple control which does exactly the same (without the ordering through 'After'), but resolves tokens - might need something clever to get it working in the sandbox but I'm sure it's possible ;)

Comment: Jackpot - Works great!  Thanks.
(but you may want to change corec4.css to corev4.css for the next person who cuts and pastes your answer into their solution :-)

Comment: Done! Glad it worked :)

Answer (score 3):

I have experienced this issue a few times and I always end up doing the same thing whenever the issue occurs to me. I simply put the CSS file in the **layouts** folder under 14 hive.

*Program files\Common files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extension\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS*

From here all your sites, being root or sub, can reach it.

Both `<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="/_layouts/My.css" After="corec4.css" runat="server"/>` and `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_layouts/My.css" />` works this way.

Style Library works too, but can be tricky. If you use Style Library to store your CSS files, try putting `%20` in between `Style%20Library`. Like so:

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="$SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style%20Library/My.css" After="corec4.css" runat="server"/>
```